# How to use multiple Active Admin instances for Complete Separate Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, multiple-instances

I have 2 models:

- Users
- Suppliers

and I want to provide 2 isolated Active Admin interfaces.
They both have devise routes:

```
devise_for :users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
devise_for :suppliers,   ActiveAdmin::Devise.config (can I somehow say ActiveAdmin2::Devise.config)
```

User will have access to Products, Orders and Supplier will have access to products only.

Ideally, I want to have different Folders in the app and present different data.

**user/order.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  filter :email
  filter :created_at  , :label => "Order Creation Date"
  filter :order_created
```

**supplier/order.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order do
  filter :email
```

Is there any way to initialize 2 ActiveAdmin Classes and run them in parallel?

Any other better way to make it work under the same website/app?

Comment: I try to avoid separating the problem into 2 different Apps which share the same DB if that helps

Comment: How to create separate login for both user and supplier.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use namespaces for this.

```
ActiveAdmin.register Order, namespace: :supplier do
  # will be available at /supplier/orders
end

ActiveAdmin.register Order, namespace: :user do
  # available at /user/orders
end
```

You can customize the authentication for each namespace in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

For example:

```
  config.default_namespace = :user

  config.namespace :supplier do |supplier|
    supplier.authentication_method = :authenticate_supplier_user!
    supplier.current_user_method = :current_supplier_user
    supplier.logout_link_path = :destroy_supplier_user_session_path
    supplier.root_to = 'orders#index'
  end

  config.namespace :user do |user|
    user.authentication_method = false
    user.current_user_method = :current_user
    user.logout_link_path = false
```

More info on: http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#namespaces