# Multiple namespaces on Rails ActiveAdmin issues

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I'm using active_admin and having issues setting up multiple namespaces.

Relevant files:

config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
config.load_paths = [File.join(Rails.root, "app", "active_admin")]
config.default_namespace = :superadmin

config.namespace :superadmin do |superadmin|
  superadmin.site_title = "superadmin"
  superadmin.authentication_method = :authenticate_superadmin_user!
end

config.namespace :admins do |admins|
  admins.site_title = "admins"
  admins.authentication_method = :authenticate_admin_user!
end
```

Then I have two subfolders, `/admins` and `/superadmin`:

app/active_admin/superadmin/dashboard:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard" do
  ...
```

app/active_admin/superadmin/product_product.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Product::Product, as: Product do
  ...
```

So far, so good.

Now, I can't seem to figure out how to add a dashboard for admins (or any other pages/models) without it blowing up.

If I go to `localhost:3000/admins`, I get the error `uninitialized constant Admins::DashboardController`.

I've tried adding:

app/active_admin/admins/dashboard.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard do
  ...
```

(which does nothing)

And namespaced:

app/active_admin/admins/dashboard.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Dashboard, namespace: "admins" do
  ...
```

which gives the error:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'admins_root' 
You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, 
or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource 
with the same naming
```

I've also tried adding the subfolders in the load_paths:

```
config.load_paths = [
  File.join(Rails.root, "app", "active_admin"),
  File.join(Rails.root, "app", "active_admin", "admins"),
  File.join(Rails.root, "app", "active_admin", "superadmin")
]
```

Please note that I've looked at the following, but none seem to actually work...

- http://activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#namespaces
- [2 Namespaces of activeadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877139/2-namespaces-of-activeadmin)
- [How to use multiple Active Admin instances for Complete Separate Models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12386535/how-to-use-multiple-active-admin-instances-for-complete-separate-models)

EDIT:

I've also tried to remove `config.default_namespace` and the only thing that did was break `localhost:3000/superadmin` so that it has the error:
`uninitialized constant Superadmin::DashboardController`